# Accessing Web Application in Localhost

Tags: tomcat, web

I have a Web Application hosted in Apache Tomcat server in my local machine. 
If I want to run the Application in my local I access using  the URL :

```
http://localhost:6060:/ApplName
```

If any other machine which is connected to My LAN need to use, it can be done using the URL :

`http://myHostName:6060/ApplnName`

Is there any way to access the Application in My local server without giving the Port number and Application name in the URL. Just by giving the URL as :

```
http://myHostName/   (or) http://myHostName/ApplName
```

P.S : I have only one Application hosted in My local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can see how you can do it: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

In TOMCAT_INSTALL_DIR/conf/server.xml search for

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector port="8080" … />
```

and change it to

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 80 -->
<Connector port="80" … />
```

Comment: Most simple and precise approach

Comment: This is unlikely to work on Linux where non-root users can't bind to ports < 1024. Don't run Tomcat as root!

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to achieve this is to use Apache HTTPd to proxy requests to Tomcat.

1. Install Apache HTTPd
2. Enable mod_proxy
3. Edit httpd.conf:

*httpd.conf*

```
ProxyPass /ApplName http://localhost:6060/ApplName
ProxyPassReverse /ApplName http://localhost:6060/ApplName
```

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html for more information.